# Installing SATA 1TB 8MB Seagate ST1000LM024 5400rpm

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, support

I'm installing Ubuntu 11.10 on "Seagate ST1000LM024 5400rpm" which is "1T HDD/8G SSD" disk.

- Do I need to do something to use features of hybrid HDD/SSD?
- If this disk doesn't support Ubuntu or the other Linux, should I use this 8G SSD as a /boot partition?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a hybrid drive. In any case, with hybrid drives you can't access the SSD part of the drive manually as the caching is all handled transparently by the drive's firmware (which means it works with all operating systems).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Though I didn't try access the SSD part, I could see the 8G SSD part on the Disk Manager. You mean, I can't use 8G SSD even if it is visible?

Comment: If you can see a 8GB SSD in there it isn't inside that seagate drive because, like I said before, you don't have any kind of access to the SSD part, nor can you see it with any kind of disk utility as that's all handled transparently. Hybrid drives are just regular HDDs as far as the Operating System is concerned. Also, there's no mention of a Momentus XT (Seagate's hybrid line) with 1GB capacity: http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/laptops/laptop-hdd/ Oh, and the Momentus XT is a 7200rpm drive not 5400 like what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your specifications, you've got a Samsung Model [http://134.204.240.102/files/staticfiles/support/docs/samsung-ds/100698122c.pdf] of the 1TB/8GB Momentus, and yes, the 8GB SanDisk iSSD P4 will be visible in your partitioner.

However, even if you tried, you'd simply be told that you CANNOT partion the SSD part as such --- which answers your 2nd question imlicitly.